# Symfony api platform operation route prefix in YAML format

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Does anyone know how to write this annotation in YAML?

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#prefixing-all-routes-of-all-operations

I've tried adding the parameter to my YAML config but it does not work.

I tried this:

```
resources:
  App\Entity\Book:
    attributes:
      routePrefix: /v1
      ...
    collectionOperations:
      ...
```

And

```
resources:
  App\Entity\Book:
    routePrefix: /v1
    attributes:
      ...
    collectionOperations:
      ...
```

And this

```
resources:
  App\Entity\Book:
    properties:
      routePrefix: /v1
      ...
    collectionOperations:
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more verbose synthax is :

```
@ApiResource(attributes={"route_prefix"="/library"})
```

So, I think is :

```
resources:
  App\Entity\Book:
    attributes:
      route_prefix: /v1
      ...
    collectionOperations:
      ...
```